# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los datos de la base de datos en <select>? (PHP)

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con los **select** en el cuál no consigo como mostrar los datos de la base de datos en ellos. Es decir, si en la columna 'pincode' de la tabla users tengo **"4321"**, que en los 4 **select** que tengo muestre en cada uno un número, algo así:

[image]

```
$account = $db->real_escape_string($_POST["select_account"]);
                $getinfouser = $db->query("SELECT id,username,rank,look,motto,credits,pixels,points,pais,tarea,online,pincode FROM users WHERE username = '" . $account . "'");
                if(mysqli_num_rows($getinfouser)) {
                    while($di = $getinfouser->fetch_row()) {
                        if($di[10] == "0"){
                        $name = $di[1];
                        $rank = $di[2];
                        if(HK_Rank >= $rank) {
                            $id = $di[0];
                            $look = $di[3];
                            $motto = $di[4];
                            $credits = $di[5];
                            $pixels = $di[6];
                            $points = $di[7];
                            $pais = $di[8];
                            $tarea = $di[9];
                            $pincode = $di[11];

                            echo "<form method='post'>
                            <div style='float:right'>
                            <img src='https://www.habbo.es/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure=".$look."&direction=4&head_direction=4&gesture=sml&action=wlk&size=l'>
                            </div>
                                <span>Usuario ID</span><br>
                                <input type='text' value='" . $id . "' disabled>
                                <br><br>
                                    <span><b>Usuario</b></span><br>
                                    <input type='text' name='usernamec' value='" . $name. "'>
                                    <br><br>

                                            <span>Rango</span><br>
                                        <select name='rankc'>
                                        <option value='". $rank ."' selected>Rango actual</option>
                                        <option value='1'>Usuario</option>
                                        <option value='2'>Vip</option>
                                        <option value='3'>Inter</option>
                                        <option value='4'>Constructor(a)</option>
                                        <option value='5'>Publicista</option>
                                        <option value='6'>Encargado(a) de publicidad</option>
                                        <option value='7'>Bot</option>
                                        <option value='8'>Moderador(a)</option>
                                        <option value='9'>Game master</option>
                                        <option value='10'>Colaborador(a)</option>
                                        <option value='11'>Supervisor(a)</option>
                                        <option value='12'>Administrador(a)</option>
                                        <option value='13'>Manager</option>
                                        <option value='14'>Encargado(a)</option>
                                        </select><br>
                                        <b>Rango seleccionado:</b> ".$rank."
                                        <br><br>

                                    <span><b>Misión</b></span><br>
                                        <input type='text' value='" . $motto . "' name='mottoc'>
                                        <br><br>

                                    <span><b>Créditos</b></span><br>
                                        <input type='text' value='" . $credits . "' name='creditsc'>
                                    <br><br>    

                                    <span><b>Pixeles</b></span><br>
                                        <input type='text' value='" . $pixels . "' name='pixelsc'>
                                    <br><br>

                                    <span><b>Diamantes</b></span><br>
                                        <input type='text' value='" . $points . "' name='pointsc'>
                                    <br><br>";
                                if(HK_Rank >= 12 && $rank > 2){
                                    echo "<span><b>Pin de acceso</b></span><br>
                                    <!--<input type='text' value='".$pincode."' name='pincodec' maxlength='4'><br>-->
                                    <select name = 'key1' style='width:40px'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select>
<select name = 'key2' style='width:40px'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select>
<select name = 'key3' style='width:40px'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select>
<select name = 'key4' style='width:40px'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select><br>
                                    <i>Introduce el código de acceso para el usuario...</i>
                                    <br><br>
                                    <span><b>Ocultar/Mostrar usuario</b></span><br>
                                    <select name='statusc'>
                                    <option value='1'>Mostrar</option>
                                    <option value='0'>Ocultar</option>
                                    </select><br>
                                    <i>Mostrar o ocultar el usuario en la sección staff o alfa...</i>
                                    <br><br>
                                    ";
                                }

                                    echo "<span><b>Tarea</b></span><br>
                                        <select name='tareaType'>
                                        <option value='".$tarea."' selected>Tarea actual</option>
                                        <option value=''>Ninguno</option>
                                        <option value='Encargado de moderación'>Encargado de moderación</option>
                                        <option value='Encargado de diversión'>Encargado de diversión</option>
                                        <option value='Encargado de publicidad'>Encargado de publicidad</option>
                                        <option value='Seguridad y reportes'>Moderación</option>
                                        <option value='Administración general'>Administración</option>
                                        <option value='Diversión'>Game master</option>
                                        <option value='Publicista'>Publicista</option>
                                        <option value='Baw'>Construcción</option>
                                        <option value='Soporte de ayuda'>Bot</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <br>
                                        <b>Tarea seleccionada:</b> ".$tarea."
                                        <br><br>
                            <input type='submit' value='Guardar' class='btsubmit' name='modify_account'>
                                    </form>";
```

Parte del **select** del pincode:

```
$pincodec = $_POST["key1"] . $_POST["key2"] . $_POST["key3"] . $_POST["key4"]; // Para unir los 4 <select> en 1.
<select name = 'key1' style='width:40px'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select>
<select name = 'key2' style='width:40px'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select>
<select name = 'key3' style='width:40px'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select>
<select name = 'key4' style='width:40px'>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
</select>
```

Otra cosa que también quería es desactivar el input donde muestra el nombre del usuario, le coloco al final **disabled** pero al actualizar datos no se actualiza ni envía nada. Soy novato, perdonen. Este input es el **WHERE** del **UPDATE** de la consulta del código que mostré más arriba.

```
<input type='text' name='usernamec' value='" . $name. "' disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría algo así, ojo no he probado el código, probablemente tenga errores de sintaxis ;-)

```
<?php
function miSelect($nombre,$valor)
{
        $salida = "<select name = 'key1' style='width:40px'>";
        for($x=1; $x<10; $x++)
        {
                if($valor == $x)
                        $salida .= " <option value='$x' selected >$x</option>";
                else
                        $salida .= "<option value='$x'>$x</option>";
        }
        $salida .= "</select>";
        return $salida;
}

echo miSelect("key1",$_POST["key1"]);
echo miSelect("key2",$_POST["key2"]);
echo miSelect("key3",$_POST["key3"]);
echo miSelect("key4",$_POST["key4"]);
```

Comment: Oh, lo probaré pero. Me podrías decir como funciona.

Comment: Me sale error **undefined index: key1, key2, key3 y key4.**

Comment: Ese código deberías ponerlo al recibir mediante POST los parámetros key1, key2....